# No null Pointer Exception caught - Image is not displaying on Touch imageview and Imageview?

Tags: android, image, android-fragments, android-imageview

I am creating a camera app which has an option to zoom and crop captured image,so i have extended  TouchImageView class, and i have loaded the image using the displayImage function from the Universal Image Loader library.My Problem is when i am calling the displayimage funcntion it is loading ,but the  image is not displaying on the TouchImageView .When i compile the project there is no any null pointer issues all are loading correctly,but why the image is not displaying on the imageview? I could not understand the reason behind the issue ,can anyone help?and i have also tried normal imageview ,but same problem is there ,So i think this is not the problem of Touch Imageview ,Can anyone help me to find the problem??

Fragment to load the image

ImageViewsFragment.java

```
public class ImageViewsFragment extends android.app.Fragment {

DisplayImageOptions options;
ImageLoaderConfiguration config;
int someVarA;
String someVarB;
String image=null;
TouchImageView touchImageView;


public ImageViewsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    // UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
    DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheOnDisc(true).cacheInMemory(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            getActivity().getApplicationContext())
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
            .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
            .discCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024).build();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    // END - UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP


    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
           .build();

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    image = bundle.getString("imagepath");
    Log.e("image url", "value"+ "" + image);
  // Uri myUri = Uri.parse(imageURL);

  try{

    View rootView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_views, container, false);
  touchImageView = (TouchImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imagetoedit);
    touchImageView.setMaxZoom(4f);
   touchImageView.setMinZoom(1f);
  //  touchImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    try {

  imageLoader.displayImage(image, touchImageview, options, new     ImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String s, View view) {
            Log.e("Loading","started");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String s, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            Log.e("Loading","Failed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String s, View view, Bitmap bitmap) {
            Log.e("Loading","onLoadingComplete");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String s, View view) {
            Log.e("Loading","onLoadingCancelled " + s);
        }
    });
   }
 catch (Exception e){
    Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);

}
     }catch(Exception e){
     Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(),e);
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_views, container,    false);
}

 }
```

frament.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="project1.example.com.instacam_fragment.imageEditing.ImageViewsFragment">



<project1.example.com.instacam_fragment.imageEditing.TouchImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:id="@+id/imagetoedit" />
```

Output on Compile

```
this = {ImageViewsFragment@830031690208}  "ImageViewsFragment{41be79e0 #0     id=0x7f0c0050}"
inflater = {PhoneLayoutInflater@830033688376} 
container = {FrameLayout@830033511976} 
savedInstanceState = null
defaultOptions = {DisplayImageOptions@830030282056} 
config = {ImageLoaderConfiguration@830030038664} 
imageLoader = {ImageLoader@830030291280} 
options = {DisplayImageOptions@830030026976} 
bundle = {Bundle@830030261408}     "Bundle[{imagepath=content://media/external/images/media/8732}]"
rootView = {FrameLayout@830033599776} 
image = {String@830030087192} "content://media/external/images/media/8732"
touchImageView = {TouchImageView@830033966888}
```

Comment: Did you check if your image path proper ?

Comment: And i have also tried path of some images from another websites

Comment: First change this  `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_views, container,    false);` to `return rootView;`

Comment: @Piyush Gupta : I wonder what was happened actually !! the problem is resolved !!,Feel Sorry to disturbing you for this simple mistake . it is working properly.Thank you very much

Comment: The problem was with the return statement.

Comment: Yes. Because you'r second time inflating the view which was incorrect !

Comment: BTW , Glad to help you !

Comment: Thanx a ton you saved my time ,already wasted 2 days for this issue...Thank you :)

Comment: Oh.. Two days ? Well its quite not good. You can ask me on Google+ whenever you need help. You can get my gmail id from stackoverflow profile !

Comment: Oh! That's great !! Thank you .. :)

Answer (score 0):

From your code , you have taken different instances of Imageloader to initialise configurations and to setImage. In other words you never initialised the "imageloader" you are using.

Use the same instance, like this:

```
imageloader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    // imageloader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getActivity()));
    thumboptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.user)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.user).cacheOnDisk(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888).considerExifParams(true)
            .cacheInMemory(true).displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(0))
            .build();
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            getActivity()).defaultDisplayImageOptions(thumboptions)
            .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
            .diskCacheExtraOptions(100, 100, null).threadPoolSize(10)
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .memoryCache(new UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache(2 * 1024 * 1024))

            .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO)
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple())
            .build();
    imageloader.init(config);
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanx for replying me ,the problem was with the returned value,I have resolved it with Mr.Piyush Gupta's answer.Thank you

Comment: yup. I got it.
 but stil you should make the change which I pointed to. :p

Comment: @Jennifer Did you send ?